# Obtener meses en String ordenados a como están en el calendario

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, sql

Tengo una entidad llamada periodo que tiene un atributo String mes en donde se guarda el mes por su nombre en español (Enero, Febrero, Marzo, etc...)

Lo que quiero es una query o alguna otra solución para obtener los periodos, pero ordenados a como están en el calendario, estoy usando jpa.

Comment: Creo que tu código de lo que tienes ayudaria un poco.

Comment: Debes compartir código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estas  pidiendo no se soluciona solo con un query.

Como tenes los meses como strings, entonces nadie va a poder ordenarlos arbitrariamente (porque aunque te suene logico, para una base de datos, ordenar strings por nombres es arbitrario).

Lo que tenes que hacer es construir otra tabla con el orden que necesitas, del estilo

Enero   1

Febrero 2

Marzo   3
...

y despues hacer una query, donde joinees ambas tablas y ordenes por la columna numerica de la tabla que creaste.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente crea la consulta que los ordene en ese orden

```
SELECT * 
FROM periodo 
ORDER BY (mes = 'Enero'), (mes = 'Febrero').....,(mes = 'Dicimebre');
```

Para no andar escribiendo siempre lo mismo puedes guardarlo en un procedimiento almacenado, si lo quieres hacer desde java hay interfaces para que crees tu método de ordenamiento, puedes echarle un ojo
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Cuidado que el OP habla de JPA, es decir que la consulta es JPQL, no SQL. Y eso no me parece JPQL válido.